# If $T : V \to V$ is linear transformation that satisfies $T\circ T=0$, which statement is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> If $T: V \to V$ is a linear transformation of vector space $V$ and $T\circ T=0$, then:
>
> a) $\ker T \subseteq \operatorname{image} T$
>
> b) $\operatorname{image} T \subseteq \ker T$
>
> c) $T = 0$
>
> d) $T$ is a nonsingular linear transformation.

**My Try:** As $T(T(x))=0$ that means $\operatorname{image} T \subseteq \ker T$.
But kernel and image are always disjoint, except $0$ is always common in them.
That means the only possibility is $T(x)=0$ for every $x\in V$. So it is a zero linear transformation.

But on the answer sheet, option (d) is given as correct.

Comment: The correct answer is b. Your claim that kernel and image are always disjoint is false, take e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Not sure why they put d as $T$ is always singular (unless $V$ is zero-dimensional I guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image and kernel are not always transverse; consider for example $$T : V \to V, \qquad T(v, w) := (w, 0) .$$

Certainly (d) cannot be correct, as it implies $\det (T \circ T) = (\det T)^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Is my explanation is correct?  Which is correct option (b)  or (c)

Comment: I got it,  range nd kernel are not disjoint so option b is correct